# In React JSX file, how do I check that something is defined in my array?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, undefined, jsx

I'm using React 16.13.0.  I have the following component ...

```
import React from 'react';
import {FormControl, FormLabel} from 'react-bootstrap';

const Input = (props) => {
    return (
  <div className="form-group">
      <FormLabel>{props.title}</FormLabel>
      <FormControl
            type={props.type}
            id={props.name}
            name={props.name}
            value={props.value}
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            onChange={props.handleChange}
          />
          {props.errors && props.errors[props.name] (
                <div className="fieldError">
                    {props.errors[props.name]}
                </div>
          )}
  </div>
    )
}

export default Input;
```

How do I check that an item is defined in an array?  Right now, the line

```
{props.errors && props.errors[props.name] (
```

is giving the error

```
TypeError: props.errors[props.name] is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are missing `&&`. So,

```
{props.errors && props.errors[props.name] (...
```

should be

```
{props.errors && props.errors[props.name] && (...
```